Bryntum gantt loading and syncing data using task store
I have a taskstore thats used to load data into my gantt chart.
Like;
const taskStore = new TaskStore({
    data : [
        {
            "id"           : 1000,
            "name"         : "Cool project",
            "percentDone"  : 50,
            "startDate"    : "2019-01-02",
            "expanded"     : true,
            "children"     : [
                {
                    "id"           : 1,
                    "name"         : "A leaf node",
                    "startDate"    : "2019-01-02",
                    "percentDone"  : 50,
                    "duration"     : 10,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

How can I;

Autoload and sync when a new task is created using lazy loading?
Sync data when a new task is created and autoload?


Assuming that you're passing the TaskStore to the project configuration of your Gantt, you need to configure the syncUrl and set autoSync property to true.
const gantt = new Gantt({
    project : {
        // Configure urls used by the built-in CrudManager
        transport : {
            sync : {
                url : 'php/sync.php'
            }
        },
        autoSync: true,
        taskStore
    }
});

Documentation Reference
